# document.execCommand("paste") doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, paste

I have an `input` HTML element like so:

```
<input title="clipboard" id="clipboard-input" type="text" value="">
```

I have binded it's paste event with jquery to a custom code which is not relevant but this binding works when ctrl+v is pressed while the element is focused.

Now, I have created a button for triggering the paste event. It's just a simple `button` with click event bound to a function with body such as this:

```
$("#clipboard-input")[0].focus();
document.execCommand("paste");
```

The click event is fired when button is pressed, clipboard element get's focused, but the paste event is not triggered by `execCommand`. Reading the documentation this should work, as it is user-initiated action which is calling the execCommand but for some reason the execCommand returns false, meaning that it failed.

I'm looking for a cross-browser solution to this problem without using flash.

**Edit:**

I have created MWE (minimal non-working example) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ygvmsyo7/4/). Try pasting something directly in the input field and the paste handler will be called, changing the text in paragraph. But when the button is pressed, the input field is focused but the execCommand fails to trigger the paste event.

Comment: I think this is a security thing, you can't read from the clipboard.

Comment: I'm not trying to read from it but fire a standard event which eventually triggers the onpaste handler. Only then the clipboard is read and this has been proven to work by trying to do ctrl+v directly while element is focused.

Now if the security thing should be even calling `execCommand("paste")` then I don't see point in having such method because if it can't be used even when the user initiated the action (by clicking the button), then it can't be ever used.

Comment: I don't think it's enough that the event is user-initiated, where did you find this claim? Think about it: if user-initiated is enough any website could read from your clipboard if they can get you to click your mouse. Can you explain what you're trying to do? Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: _I don't see point in having such method because (..) it can't be ever used_ -- it exists because at some point someone thought it was a good idea, then a vulnerability was found and the function was disabled. Doesn't seem so strange to me. The function likely still exists to avoid breaking existing code.

Comment: You might be right that the specific method was disabled by putting return false at its start. But "to avoid breaking existing code", well any code dependent on this feature WOULD be broken. Oh and for the first part, there is note [1] for the paste on the MDN site (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), which says that event handlers which are able to pop-up new window (semi-trusted) are allowed to execCommand("paste") since Firefox 41. And I believ clicking button does allow opening a new window.

Comment: Have you tried to see if it works in _designMode_? _"any code dependent on this feature WOULD be broken"_ that depends: if the code properly checks for the return value (ie `false`) nothing breaks. If you didn't check for `false` it silently fails. In either case **graceful degradation** is guaranteed. If instead they removed the function the code would throw an Error, which would likely break the whole app. That's why it's important that the function still exists.

Comment: @Halcyon sorry for not noting it in the question, at the time of your comment the example was already updated to use designMode. execCommand still not working though. The bad thing is now even input field won't work as it is overwritten by the input you try to paste there. EDIT: In fact the paste in the input field still works but you must be very careful where you click.

Comment: I tried the jsFiddle in Internet Explorer 11 and it will ask for permission to read the clipboard. Chrome and Firefox seem to just return false.

Comment: True that  I did try only FF and Chrome. Well that's the behavior, now why is it so if the docs say that it should be possible.. Someone who actually worked on this or knows the browser source code might be able to answer. To clear things out, this has become more of a question of interest since I already bypassed this problem by popping a dialog after click event with input field where the user can paste the content, but it would be still nice if this intermediate step could be taken out.

Answer (score 2):

This is a specific command works only when the browser is in design mode that is the document is turned into an editor that exposes the RTE features and the exact syntax is

```
document.execCommand(aCommandName, aShowDefaultUI, aValueArgument)
```

Ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: This is invalid answer. I can call document.execCommand("copy") when I focus editable element without problem (which means the copy event fires on focused element) and didn't have to get browser into design mode (whatever that means).

Comment: Give the entire code that you have for testing and there is no need of index value to be passed with an id $("#clipboard-input")[0]. I don't have high enough rep to comment so have to put it in answer. Read : http://help.dottoro.com/ljcvtcaw.php

Comment: I have updated question with example. Things are more complicated with this being originally written in typescript, therefore [0] is required because the $() return JQuery object while $()[0] is first HTML element of this query - the input field.

Comment: I have updated the example in the edit part so that designMode is on.. You can test this by clicking the paragraph text and writing something there. The paragraph is changed which clearly wouldn't work if the designMode was not on.. but the paste doesn't work anyway which can be verified in cosole (the return value of execCommand is false).